# "Aim life with Money"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, slang

I am planning for a tattoo with an image of a target, and the caption I thought of is **"Aim life with money"**. Money being an arrow, and life being the "center of the target".

I want to make a point, something like "live life to its fullest, and this is only possible with money so focus on your career". The reason is that I lost my job and now miss the fun in life because I can't afford it.

Am I getting it (the caption) right? Does it express what I'm trying to convey?

Comment: If you're going to have the tattoo for the rest of your life, you should probably think hard about whether you really want this sentiment to "define" you in years to come. As the Beatles said many decades ago, [money can't buy you love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can't_Buy_Me_Love) (or indeed, [happiness](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130611233555AAegsLH)). I suggest a temporary tattoo saying [**Gizza job**](http://www.thisishullandeastriding.co.uk/Gizza-job-phonebox-man-got-sack/story-16928095-detail/story.html#axzz2dSzNtHkc), for something a bit more light-hearted.

Comment: ...but there's always [Money makes the world go round](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_'Money_makes_the_world_go_around'_mean) for an established turn of phrase that won't necessarily pigeonhole you as a [breadhead](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/breadhead).

Comment: adhineth, it is not obvious what your suggested caption means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The four-word phrase you've provided makes no sense to me as a native English speaker.

It would become interpretable, though, if you added one preposition:

> *Aim **for** life with money*

Whether or not that conveys what you are trying to say is up for debate.

Some might parse the phrase as

> Aim for (life with money)

pointing to a philosophy where a chief goal would be to have life with money.  In that context, "aim" could mean one of two things:

- *My life's goal (aim) is to get money*
- *My goal (aim) is to get myself into a position where I can get money*

The first sounds quite materialistic; the second a bit less so, because it could be thought of as incentive to work hard in school, etc.

Others might parse the phrase as

> Aim for life (with money)

This reading would imply: *We can live an exciting life by using our money to live an exciting life*. It's a bit ambigous because the word *life* can take on several different meanings and nuances; pay particular attention to [Defs. #4 & #12 at Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/life).

You could also use the preposition *at*:

> *Aim **at** life with money*

I would interpret this to mean, roughly: *I'd rather die rich than die poor.*

If it were my tattoo, I think I'd opt for the phrase:

> ***Stay focused***

this will exhort you to focus on your career aspirations without making it appear as though you are a shallow person who can't see the good in life unless your wallet is full. Some consider the love of money to be the root of all evil, but I've not heard too many people talk about the dangers of *focus*.

Comment: [The Dangers of Focus](http://www.sfgate.com/news/article/Focusing-192-lasers-on-one-little-target-3201241.php). ;) +1!

Comment: @Wendi - Believe it or not, I thought about lasers when I wrote that last line, but I decided to leave it as an exercise for the reader. Nice catch!